# I was trying to release an app with android studio but it gave me this error can you help me?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\STEFANO\Desktop\Delia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\release\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4e767cf8.). Check logs for more details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4e767cf8.

Comment: Please provide some details. What exactly are you trying to build here? How does gradle script look like?

Answer (score 1):

you must check your values/xml (string, style, colors...) for typos like:

- Symbol ' escape as \'
- Check the colors start with #